# MAC OS X Server Lion - how to join two subnets?

Tags: vpn, mac-osx-server, subnet

I've got two routers connected to two different providers. I also have Mac OS X Lion server connected to both of them, so it looks like this:

```
   [INTERNET]        [INTERNET]
       |                  |
    [router]          [router]
       |                  |
[192.168.1.0/24]  [192.168.10.0/24]
       |                  | 
       |---[Mac Server]---|
       |                  |
  [computers #A]    [computers #B]
```

No what I'm trying to do is to make computers from subnet #A see computers from subnet #B and vice-versa. Mac Server has 192.168.1.100 and 192.168.10.100 IPS and it sees both networks. However when I'm setting VPN I can see only a network depending from which subnet I connect from. So if I connect to VPN via 192.168.1.100 I can see 192.168.1.0/24 network and ONLY 192.168.10.100 IP (server itself). When I connect via 192.168.10.100 I can see 192.168.10.0/24 network and ONLY 192.167.1.100.

Is there is something missing here? I didn't set any routing/nat except those created magically by MAC OS X itself. It also doesn't have to be via VPN - I just want connect those subnets, nothing more.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want computers from subnet A to be able to see subnet B, or do you only want the VPN client to see both subnets?

Answer (score 1):

If you want subnet A to see subnet B, you will need to add a static route on the server, and then also add the route to each PC

Server:

```
route -n add 192.168.1.0/24 192.168.1.100
route -n add 192.168.10.0/24 192.168.10.100
```

Clients

```
[root@192.168.10.x]# route -n add 192.168.1.0/24 192.168.10.100
[root@192.168.1.x]# route -n add 192.168.10.0/24 192.168.1.100
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your help - this was a solution which I was thinking of initially. However I can't make it to work :( I'm trying to do a traceroute and I'm not even reaching .10.100. Here is my route table row:

    192.168.1          192.168.10.100     UGSc            0        3     en1

 - Can i debug it other way than traceroute?

Answer (score 0):

> computers from subnet #A see computers from subnet #B

What do you mean "see"? You have two separate broadcast domains, they will not see each other by Bonjour, unless you do enough DNS fiddling to configure Wide-Area-Bonjour.

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=874886

If you mean "can access other computers if I give the remote IP address", you need routing, as per David Houde's answer.